# How to select a single row in table on selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium-ide

I am testing a web application in selenium IDE. I want to access a single row of table, but i am unable to select, plzzz tell me what command and target i should write?

Comment: A question with context will get better and more focussed answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is ambiguous.

However I am assuming that you are trying to fetch the data/text available in a specific row of a table.

You can use the *storeText* command for this purpose. The syntax is as follows:

```
command: storeText
Target: locator
value: variable_name
```

I would suggest that you use **Xpath** as the *locator*. In the above command *variable_name* refers to the variable that will store the text which is fetched using the command.

To select a single row of the table, you need to know how to write [Xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp) for the required row.

Now to access the data in each of the rows in the table you can use *storeText* command within a *while* loop, and index that Xpath (element locator). As you store the text in the variable in each iteration, you can use the *echo* command to display the same onto the log. The required data can be extracted from the log using grep command in Linux.